# Can't add new translation to nextjs next-translate common namespace

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

```
[next-translate] "common:removed_shareholder" is missing in current namespace configuration. Try adding "removed_shareholder" to the namespace "common".
```

So I want to add more translations to my common.json file but it doesnt work for me. I have translations in both localization files:

```
"registration_history_change_values": {
        "address": "The address has changed",
        "owner": "The founder has changed",
        "officer": "The leader has changed",
        "main_activity": "The main activity has changed",
        "name_national": "The name has been changed in Kazakh",
        "name": "The name has changed",
        "company_size": "Company size changed",
         // new translations below
        "added_shareholder": "Added shareholder",
        "removed_shareholder ": "Removed shareholder",
        "total_history": "Total"
    },
```

Comment: Don't you have an extra whitespace in `"removed_shareholder "`?

Comment: this warn happens to other new translations too
/// upd. i'll check if removing whitespace helps
/// upd2. it didnt

Comment: What other translations? All the ones you've shown us?

Comment: all new translations*
there's only whitespace in 1 of them

Comment: It seems to be accessing the `common` namespace (`common:removed_shareholder`) but these translations are scoped under `registration_history_change_values`. Can you show us how you're trying to access the new translations in the code?

Comment: you asked me to see how i try to access these translations and i noticed what i was doing wrong. there was a ref called for example translRef that holds this ```t('registration_history_change_values', {}, { returnObjects: true })``` and i was doing ```t('removed_shareholder')``` but should've do like this ```translRef.current['removed_shareholder'] ```

Answer (score 0):

As my new translations were scoped under `registration_history_change_values`, I was trying to access translations the wrong way.

I've made a ref that stores an object `current` with all translations I want from  `registration_history_change_values`. So now I can access translations by doing translationRef.current['removed_shareholder'].

Thanks *@juliomalves* for helping.